# Go variable doesn't get overwritten in if statement

Tags: go

```
duration := 1 * time.Hour
if true {
    duration, err := time.ParseDuration("5s")
    _ = duration // if I don't have this, it gives me a duration declared not used error
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

fmt.Println(duration) // prints 1 hour
```

I guess the issue here is that duration is declared again as local var within if statement. Is there a syntactically good way to resolve this?

Comment: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope

Answer (score 9):

Indeed, you declare the `duration` variable again in the `if` block. My way to do this is to declare `err` before the `if` block (usually at the beginning of the function, as an `error` variable is pretty much always needed...).

```
var err error
duration := 1 * time.Hour
if true {
    duration, err = time.ParseDuration("5s")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this it worked. But if statement shouldn't be a closure like function call, I feel like this should be a bug that golang should fix itself?

Comment: That's not a bug, this behaviour is conform to the specifications. It was already signaled as a Golang issue, but it was rejected for this reason: https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5990

Comment: Sick! I guess they are just want to be very strict to this language. That's really helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

The question is whether you want `duration` to be overwritten when `time.ParseDuration` returns an error or not. If not, then I would write

```
duration := 1 * time.Hour
if true {
    d, err := time.ParseDuration("5s")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        duration = d
    }
}
```

If you don't care about the old value in the case of an error, @julienc's answer is just as good.

Comment: So every time I need declare a new var? I feel like this should be a pretty common logical use case in any code...

Answer (score 1):

Go is a block-structured programming language. Generally, variables are declared with minimal scope.

The variable `duration` is declared and used in the outer (`func`) scope and is also set in the inner (`if`) scope. The `err` variable is declared and used in the inner (`if`) scope. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    duration := 1 * time.Hour
    if true {
        var err error
        duration, err = time.ParseDuration("5s")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(duration)
}
```

Output:

```
5s
```

Using a short variable declaration won't work. A short variable declaration can only redeclare variables that are originally declared earlier in the same block.

```
func main() {
    duration := 1 * time.Hour
    if true {
        duration, err := time.ParseDuration("5s")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(duration)
}
```

Error:

```
duration declared and not used
```

The variable `duration` is declared and used in the outer (`func`) scope. It is also declared (not redeclared) and set, but not used, in the inner (`if`) scope.

References:

[Block (programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_%28programming%29)

[Block scope (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Block_scope)

[The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)

[The Go Programming Language Specification: Blocks](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks)

[The Go Programming Language Specification: Declarations and scope](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)

[The Go Programming Language Specification: Short variable declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)